# Allow Googlebot to crawl dynamically generated product pages

Tags: google-search, javascript, web-crawlers, googlebot

I have been doing some reading into how Googlebot crawls javascript generated webpages but am still a little confused on it.

Say I have a web page for company XYZ Inc that has 5 general products like bath towels and Pencils.

How do I allow Googlebot to index www.xyzinc.com/products/bath-towels so that it shows up in the google search results such as:

```
XYZ Inc. - Bath Towels
www.xyzinc.com/products/bath-towels
some description here
```

My one idea was to created a Site Map that has a generated list of all the products on the page in nested links with links that I can feed to the Google Search Console, but I do not know if that is the right way to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do anything particularly special to enable Google to index dynamically generated content.

You don't specify how your website URL's are formed in your question but as it is from dynamic content it would either be using clean URL's that have been rewritten by the server using URL rewrite rules, or using query strings on the end of a single file.

If you are using query strings then you would have to create rewrite rules to create the clean URL's if that is how you want Google to display the URL's.

If you already have rewritten URL's then there is nothing else that you need to do.

Google indexes based not just on a sitemap but also on links. As such as long as each product in your database is linked to using an `a` link in your site somehow then Google will identify the product and crawl it. If you want the URL in the SERP to display as you have shown in your example then you have to use URL rewriting and make sure all your generated links use the rewritten URL's as whatever URL is provided in the link and/or sitemap to access the page is the URL that Google will show. As for the description strictly speaking there is no specific way to choose what is displayed as Google will pick the appropriate content from the page for this section based on the keywords used in the search.

Comment: *As for the description strictly speaking there is no specific way to choose what is displayed...* Though limited, you certainly can manipulate when Google will use you description meta-tag fairly well depending on how well you craft the description meta-tag. You cannot get all cases, however, you can get much or most of the the typical cases.